# AsymptoticDSolveValue fails at some value

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

I have the following simple code for obtaining the asymptotic behavior of $r(\rho)$ at infinity. The routine works well with $q=-1$ and $q=1/3$ but fails for the rest of the values where $q<1$ (e.g. $q=0$). What could be the problem here? My main goal here is to obtain an asymptotic solution $r(\rho)$ given a particular value of q. Thanks

```
 q = 0; b0 = 1;
 sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{r'[\[Rho]] == Sqrt[1 - (b0/r[\[Rho]])^(1 - q)], r[0] == b0}, r[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], \[Infinity], 1}]
```

Comment: The answer to your question as written is simple.  `AsymptoticDSolveValue` does not know how to provide an asymptotic solution for those values of `q`.  Is that what you are looking for, or do you wish to obtain an asymptotic solution for some particular value of q?

Comment: My goal is to obtain an asymptotic solution $r(\rho)$ given a particular value of q.

Comment: For all values of `q` and `r[0] = b0`, the ODE has an exact solution.  It is equal to `b0` for all rho.

Comment: Yeah, that's the leading term. But I also want to know the next leading orders

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `b0==1` you'll find an analytical solution looking for `\[Rho][r]` ("inverse problem"):

```
rho = DSolveValue[{1 == \[Rho]'[r] Sqrt[1 - 1/r^(1 - q)] , \[Rho][1] == 0}, \[Rho], r]
(*Function[{r}, -((2 (-Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[-1 + q] Sqrt[(r - r^q)/r]Gamma[3/2 + 1/(1 - q)] 
+Sqrt[1 - q] r Sqrt[r^-q (-r + r^q)]Gamma[1 + 1/(1 - q)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (-3 +q)/(2 (-1 + q)), 1 + (-3 + q)/(2 (-1 + q)), r^(1 - q)]))/(Sqrt[1 - q] (-3 + q) Sqrt[(r - r^q)/r] Gamma[1 + 1/(1 - q)]))]*)

Plot[Table[rho[r], {q, -1, 1 - .1, .1}], {r, 1, 100},AxesLabel -> {"r", "rho[r]"}]
```

[image]

The asymptotic behavior evaluates to `rho[r]/r~1, r->Infinity`

```
Table[{q, Normal[Series[rho[r] /r, {r, Infinity, 0}] ]}, {q, -1,1 - 1/10, 1/10}] // Simplify[#, r > 1] & // N    
(*{{-1., 1.}, {-0.9, 1.}, {-0.8, 1.}, {-0.7, 1.}, {-0.6, 1.}, {-0.5,1.}, {-0.4, 1.},...}*)
```

For special values   it's possible to invert the Series by hand( unfortunately `InverseSeries` doesn't work here)

**case `q==0`:**

```
ser = Normal[Series[rho[r] /. q -> 0, {r, Infinity, 0}]] // Simplify[#, r > 0] &
(*-(1/2) + r + Log[2] + Log[r]/2*)
```

->Targeting guessing

```
Series[\[Rho] - ser /.r -> \[Rho] - 1/2  Log[\[Rho]] + 1/2 (1 - 2 Log[2]), {\[Rho],Infinity, 1}] // Simplify
(*SeriesData[\[Rho], DirectedInfinity[1], {Rational[1, 4] (-1 + Log[4] + Log[\[Rho]])}, 1, 2, 1]*)
```

gives the inverse expansion `r ~ \[Rho] + 1/2 (1 - 2 Log[2])- 1/2  Log[\[Rho]]`

**case `q==1/2`:**

```
ser = Normal[Series[rho[r] /. q -> 1/2, {r, Infinity, 0}]] // Simplify[#, r > 0] &
(*-(7/8) + Sqrt[r] + r + (3 Log[2])/2 + (3 Log[r])/8*)
```

->Targeting guessing

```
Series[\[Rho] - ser /.r -> \[Rho] -   Sqrt[\[Rho]] - 3/8 Log[\[Rho]], {\[Rho],Infinity, 1}] // Simplify
(*SeriesData[\[Rho], DirectedInfinity[1], {Rational[1, 8] (11 - 12 Log[2]),Rational[1, 16] (8 + 3 Log[\[Rho]]),Rational[1, 64] (16 + 15 Log[\[Rho]])}, 0, 3, 2]*)
```

gives the inverse expansion `r -> \[Rho] -   Sqrt[\[Rho]] - 3/8 Log[\[Rho]]`

Comment: But I am interested in the inverse of $\rho(r)$ which is $r(\rho)$.

Comment: @user583893 See my modified answer. It should be sufficient!

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware that $r\sim\rho$ in the limit $r\rightarrow\infty$, but what I need are the next leading order terms in the expansion.

Comment: @user583893  My last `Table` -command in my answer gives the series expansion of the InverseSeries, see result for q>0!